# Plot segments at the ends of the graph

Tags: plotting

Writing:

```
ParametricPlot[{x, x}, {x, 1, 2}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

I get:

[image]

I would like to know if there was a command to add after `AxesOrigin` that gave the following graph:

[image]

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ParametricPlot[{x , x Boole[1 <= x <= 2] }, {x, 0, 3},  Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

or

```
ParametricPlot[{x , x Boole[1 <= x <= 2] }, {x, 0, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 3}}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

Note: `Exclusions -> {{1,2}}` also works.

Comment: @TeM, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have to use ParametricPlot?

If not:

```
Plot[If[x < 1 || x > 2, 0, x], {x, 0, 3},
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
 Exclusions -> Automatic,
 ExclusionsStyle -> Red]
```

Comment: The options `Exclusions -> Automatic, ExclusionsStyle -> Red` do not appear to change the output in v10.1.  Are they needed in other versions?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use a two parameter ParametricPlot:

```
ParametricPlot[{x,x t}, {x,1,2}, {t,0,1}, Frame->False, AxesOrigin->{0,0}]
```

[image]

Or with `PlotStyle -> None`:

```
ParametricPlot[{x, x t}, {x, 1, 2}, {t, 0, 1},
  Frame -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotStyle -> None]
```

[image]